# In Laravel 7.x Homestead Photo is uploaded in storage properly but not displayed while fetched in blade file

Tags: laravel-7

**In ArticleController.php data is uploaded in storage directory with proper extension but in homestread database the uploaded photo data is "/tmp/phpBqfse2"**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
Article::create($this->validateForm());
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) 
{
    $fileName = $request->photo->getClientOriginalName();   
    $request->photo->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');
}
    return redirect()->route('article.index')->with('success', 'Article data has been uploaded 
    successfully');
}

**In index.blade.php the data is not fetched by the following code **

<img src="{{ asset('uploads/'. $article->photo) }}" alt="Photo">

**Note**
storage is linked
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you link your storage (`php artisan storage:link`), you access the storage by using `{{ asset('storage/and/file.png') }}`. Say how you're trying to access the 'uploads' folder, and access a jpeg, just as an example. You would do so like such:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/uploads/photo.jpeg') }}" alt="What you want">
```

Comment: <img src="{{ asset('storage/uploads/'. $article->photo) }}" alt="Photot"> but photo is not displayed in blade files

Comment: @BishwajitPaul Are you getting an errors in your console such as `404 not found` for the image?

Comment: You can check these if your errors in the console in Google Chrome's Developer Tools or Firefox's Developer Tools

Comment: When I try to open in a new window 404 not found is thrown. How can I solve it? Can I be assisted in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If file system is #type: "nfs" in Homestead.yaml in Homestead directory, files will not be displayed in Windows OS.